# vue.js3 typescript で　エラー[computedプロパティの型がComputedOptionsと一致していない]の適切な対処方法が知りたい

Tags: typescript, vue.js

###### 質問内容

提示のソースコードですが以下のコンソールログのエラー出ますこれなどうやって対処するのが適切なのでしょうか？
ChatGPTで原因は理解したのですが対処方法がわかりません。

###### 知りたいこと

エラー部の原因を対処するための適切な対処方法が知りたい

###### 利用ライブラリ

vue.js3

###### 実行したコマンド

```
vue create project //でプロジェクトを作成
npm run build //すでにあるコマンドを使用
```

###### 試したこと

ChatGPTに質問
typescriptのバージョンを最新版から4.9.5にダウンしましたが同じエラーでした。
vue.jsは３を使いたいのでダウンはしたくありません

###### chatGPTの解答

```
 自分
 [このエラーはなんですか？
　src/main.ts:5:11 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof import("/home/xxx/dev/kintone/
/*文字数関係で省略　エラーコンソール部の文章をコピペ*/
5 createApp(App).mount('#app')
]          
            
解答文[
これは、TypeScriptコンパイラがTypeScriptファイルをコンパイルする際に生成したエラーです。このエラーは、Vue.jsアプリケーションでTypeScriptを使用している場合に発生する可能性があります。

エラーメッセージの意味は、createAppメソッドに渡された引数の型が、期待される型と一致しないため、TypeScriptコンパイラがエラーを発生させたことを示しています。具体的には、createAppメソッドに渡された型が、ComponentOptionsと互換性がないということです。

このエラーは、computedプロパティの型が一致しないために発生している可能性があります。computedプロパティは、Vue.jsのリアクティブなデータを追跡するために使用されます。しかし、このエラーは、computedプロパティの型がComputedOptionsと一致していないことを示しています。

解決策としては、computedプロパティの型を修正することが挙げられます。また、Vue.jsのバージョンを確認して、適切なバージョンをインストールすることも必要です。さらに、TypeScriptの設定を確認して、正しく構成されていることを確認することも重要です。
]
```

###### package.json

```
{
  "name": "kintone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "update": "npx kintone-dts-gen --base-url https://1fi8yhu4v4n1.cybozu.com -u matsuzawatca@gmail.com -p Matsuzawa0509 --app-id 10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.4",
    "@kintone/customize-uploader": "^6.0.33",
    "@kintone/dts-gen": "^6.1.27",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "webpack": "^5.79.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/runtime-core": "^3.2.47",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

###### tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for legacy experimental decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "ES2015",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
     "moduleResolution": "node",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    // "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,               /* Allow imports to include TypeScript file extensions. Requires '--moduleResolution bundler' and either '--noEmit' or '--emitDeclarationOnly' to be set. */
    // "resolvePackageJsonExports": true,                /* Use the package.json 'exports' field when resolving package imports. */
    // "resolvePackageJsonImports": true,                /* Use the package.json 'imports' field when resolving imports. */
    // "customConditions": [],                           /* Conditions to set in addition to the resolver-specific defaults when resolving imports. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "allowArbitraryExtensions": true,                 /* Enable importing files with any extension, provided a declaration file is present. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */

    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
     "declarationDir": "./dist/types",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,                     /* Do not transform or elide any imports or exports not marked as type-only, ensuring they are written in the output file's format based on the 'module' setting. */
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
     "noImplicitAny":true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
     "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
     "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
     "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": false                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "files" : [
    "./node_modules/@kintone/dts-gen/kintone.d.ts",
    "./fields.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "./*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "typescript-vue",
      "options": {
        "template": "vue3"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

###### エラー コンソール表示

```
$ npx tsc
src/main.ts:5:11 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof import("/home/xxx/dev/kintone/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions>'.
  Type 'typeof import("/home/xxx/dev/kintone/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' is not assignable to type 'ComponentOptions<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, any, any, any>'.
    Type 'typeof import("/home/xxx/dev/kintone/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' is not assignable to type 'ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, any, any, any, string, {}, {}, string>'.
      Types of property 'computed' are incompatible.
        Type '{ <T>(getter: ComputedGetter<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): ComputedRef<T>; <T>(options: WritableComputedOptions<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): WritableComputedRef<...>; }' is not assignable to type 'ComputedOptions'.
          Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{ <T>(getter: ComputedGetter<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): ComputedRef<T>; <T>(options: WritableComputedOptions<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): WritableComputedRef<...>; }'.

5 createApp(App).mount('#app')
            ~~~


Found 1 error in src/main.ts:5
```

###### エラーVScode上

```
型 'typeof import("/home/shigurechan/dev/kintone/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' の引数を型 'Component<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions>' のパラメーターに割り当てることはできません。
  型 'typeof import("/home/shigurechan/dev/kintone/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' を型 'ComponentOptions<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, any, any, any>' に割り当てることはできません。
    型 'typeof import("/home/shigurechan/dev/kintone/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' を型 'ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, any, any, any, string, {}, {}, string>' に割り当てることはできません。
      プロパティ 'computed' の型に互換性がありません。
        型 '{ <T>(getter: ComputedGetter<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): ComputedRef<T>; <T>(options: WritableComputedOptions<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): WritableComputedRef<...>; }' を型 'ComputedOptions' に割り当てることはできません。
          型 'string' is missing in type '{ <T>(getter: ComputedGetter<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): ComputedRef<T>; <T>(options: WritableComputedOptions<T>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): WritableComputedRef<...>; }' のインデックス シグネチャがありません。ts(2345)
```

###### main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

console.log("Hello World");
createApp(App).mount('#app') // ここのApp部で波線のエラー
```

Comment: 細かくは見ていませんが、このIssueと同ケースで、コメントにあるような修正で解決できるかもしれません。 https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2627 なお、tscではSFCの型解決に不足があるのでvue-tscの利用も検討ください（また、vscodeではvolar https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html ）

Comment: 「実行したコマンド」を単純に実行だけでは現象が再現しませんでした。環境(OS、node.js、@vue/cliのそれぞれのバージョン)、`vue create project`実行時の選択の内容等を記載してください。また、実行したコマンド以外に実行したことや変更したことがあれば、それも漏らさず明記してください。変更が多すぎるというのであれば、プロジェクト全体を[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/)等にアップロードして誰でも再現できるようにしてください。